# Printing DataAdapter-generated statements

Tags: dataadapter

I am using data adapters from C#, and it would be great if there is a way to print the statements executed by data adapters for debug purpose.

I can print the statements generated by OleDbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand/GetDeleteCommand/GetInsertCommand, but those don't contain the actual values.

I'd like to print statements executed by 'DataAdapter.Update()', with all the values filled in.

Is that possible?